# Referencing outlet file's owner

Tags: ios, xcode

I can't figure out why it's crashing with "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key profilePic" in this picture.

[image]

Comment: Can you show the exception message?  It will say which class it was having a problem is.  My guess would be that you haven't set `InitialViewController` as your view controller's custom class.

Comment: In my AppDelegate "let initialViewController = UIViewController.init(nibName: "InitialViewController", bundle: nil) as! InitialViewController" gives "Could not cast value of type 'UIViewController' (0x106b835e0) to 'Playground_Project.InitialViewController' (0x10543e328)." I'm thinking this needs to be resolved first?

Comment: The file owner's Class is set to InitialViewController. Is that not enough?

Comment: I have it so:

class InitialViewController: BaseViewController

public class BaseViewController: UIViewController

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117507/discussion-between-paulw11-and-latcie).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With storyboard scenes, the view controller instance class is set by the custom class assigned to the view controller scene.  With NIB files you are responsible for initialising the correct class instance yourself:

Rather than

```
let initialViewController = UIViewController.init(nibName: "InitialViewController", bundle: nil) as! InitialViewController
```

You need to have

```
let initialViewController = InitialViewController(nibName:"InitialViewController". bundle: nil)
```